# How to change Page title in title area

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is there anyway to change the page title in title area in sharepoint 2013 foundation version. I need to change the title for each page in my site pages. Is there any way to do this within sharepoint functionality.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OOB:

> Go in List setting and change list name.

If you dont want to change list name,

Using SP Designer:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    Page Title
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: yes but i am getting the following warning `The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template.`

Comment: are you using designer manager to develop masterpage?

Comment: I am not modifying masterpage, i am using sharepoint designer